# Scripting advanced security properties in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008

Under SQL Server 2008, you can set the permissions for a given user down to the table and/or field level.

In the GUI, it's easy to select the "Securables" and apply them, but is it possible to script the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can script the security permissions (including column-level) by using the [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx) statement.

If you want to use SSMS to script the information, assign the permissions in Securables and click on the `Script` button at the top of the screen.

[alt text http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/7236/scriptperm.png](http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/7236/scriptperm.png)

Below is an example of scripting column-level permissions with T-SQL:

```
USE master
GO

/* Create test database */
CREATE DATABASE StackO
GO

USE StackO
GO

/* Create a table */
CREATE TABLE TestSelect (
  RowID INT NOT NULL,
  RowValue VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  RowProperty VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
) 

/* Populate with data */
INSERT TestSelect VALUES (1,'A','X'),(2,'A','Y')

/* Create a user */
CREATE USER SO_User WITHOUT LOGIN

/* Grant the user SELECT permissions on RowID and RowValue */
GRANT SELECT ON TestSelect (RowID) TO SO_User
GO

GRANT SELECT ON TestSelect (RowValue) TO SO_User
GO

/* Deny user SELECT permissions on RowProperty */
DENY SELECT ON TestSelect (RowProperty) TO SO_User
GO

/* Test the permissions */
EXECUTE AS USER = 'SO_User'
GO

/* Confirm select on RowID and RowValue */
SELECT RowID, RowValue FROM TestSelect
GO

/* Confirm error message on RowProperty */
SELECT RowProperty FROM TestSelect
GO

/* Go back to regular user */
REVERT
GO

/* Cleanup */
USE master
GO

DROP DATABASE StackO
GO
```

And the results:

```
RowID       RowValue
----------- --------
1           A
2           A

Msg 230, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
The SELECT permission was denied on the column 'RowProperty' 
of the object 'TestSelect", database 'SO', schema 'dbo'.
```

Comment: Thanks - I did not notice the Script button.